# Subtract value in row based on condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, cumsum

I need to subtract dates based on the progression of fault count.
Below is the table that has the two input columns `Date` and `Fault_Count`. The output columns I need are `Option1` and `Option2`. The last two columns show the date difference calculations. Basically when the Fault_Count changes I need to count the number of days from when the Fault_Count changed to the initial start of fault count. For example the Fault_Count changed to 2 on `1/4/2020`, I need to get the number of days from when the `Fault_Count` started at `0` and changed to 2 (i.e. `1/4/2020` - `1/1/2020` = `3`).

```
Date    Fault_Count Option1 Option2    Option1calc          Option2calc
1/1/2020       0       0        0       
1/2/2020       0       0        0       
1/3/2020       0       0        0       
1/4/2020       2       3        3   1/4/2020-1/1/2020    1/4/2020-1/1/2020
1/5/2020       2       0        0       
1/6/2020       2       0        0       
1/7/2020       4       3        3   1/7/2020-1/4/2020    1/7/2020-1/4/2020
1/8/2020       4       0        0       
1/9/2020       5       2        2   1/9/2020-1/7/2020    1/9/2020-1/7/2020
1/10/2020      5       0        0       
1/11/2020      0       2       -2   1/11/2020-1/9/2020   (1/11/2020-1/9/2020)*-1 as the fault resets
1/12/2020      1       1        1   1/12/2020-1/11/2020  1/12/2020-1/11/2020
```

Below is the code.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Date': ['1/1/2020', '1/2/2020', '1/3/2020', '1/4/2020', '1/5/2020', '1/6/2020', '1/7/2020', '1/8/2020', '1/9/2020', '1/10/2020', '1/11/2020', '1/12/2020'], 'Fault_Count' : [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 0, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Fault_count_diff'] = df.Fault_Count.diff().fillna(0)
df['Cumlative_Sum'] = df.Fault_count_diff.cumsum()
```

I thought I could use cumulative sum and group by to get the groups and get the differences of the first value of groups. That's as far as I could get, also I noticed that using cumulative sum was not giving me ordered groups as some of the `Fault_Count` get reset.

```
    Date        Fault_Count   Fault_count_diff    Cumlative_Sum
0   2020-01-01       0               0.0                0.0
1   2020-01-02       0               0.0                0.0
2   2020-01-03       0               0.0                0.0
3   2020-01-04       2               2.0                2.0
4   2020-01-05       2               0.0                2.0
5   2020-01-06       2               0.0                2.0
6   2020-01-07       4               2.0                4.0
7   2020-01-08       4               0.0                4.0
8   2020-01-09       5               1.0                5.0
9   2020-01-10       5               0.0                5.0
10  2020-01-11       0              -5.0                0.0
11  2020-01-12       1               1.0                1.0
```

**Desired output:**

```
         Date  Fault_Count  Option1  Option2
0  2020-01-01            0      0.0      0.0
1  2020-01-02            0      0.0      0.0
2  2020-01-03            0      0.0      0.0
3  2020-01-04            2      3.0      3.0
4  2020-01-05            2      0.0      0.0
5  2020-01-06            2      0.0      0.0
6  2020-01-07            4      3.0      3.0
7  2020-01-08            4      0.0      0.0
8  2020-01-09            5      2.0      2.0
9  2020-01-10            5      0.0      0.0
10 2020-01-11            0      2.0     -2.0
11 2020-01-12            1      1.0      1.0
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use:**

```
m1 = df['Fault_Count'].ne(df['Fault_Count'].shift(fill_value=0))
m2 = df['Fault_Count'].eq(0) & df['Fault_Count'].shift(fill_value=0).ne(0)

s = df['Date'].groupby(m1.cumsum()).transform('first')

df['Option1'] = df['Date'].sub(s.shift()).dt.days.where(m1, 0)
df['Option2'] = df['Option1'].where(~m2, df['Option1'].mul(-1))
```

---

**Details:**

Use [`Series.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) + [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) to create boolean mask `m1` which represent the boundary condition when `Fault_count` changes, similarly use [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) + [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html)  and [`Series.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) to create a boolean mask `m2` which represent the condition where `Fault_count` resets:

```
          m1           m2
0         False        False
1         False        False
2         False        False
3          True        False
4         False        False
5         False        False
6          True        False
7         False        False
8          True        False
9         False        False
10         True         True # --> Fault count reset
11         True        False
```

Use [`Series.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) on consecutive fault counts obtained using `m1.cumsum` and transform the `Date` column using [`groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
print(s)
0    2020-01-01
1    2020-01-01
2    2020-01-01
3    2020-01-04
4    2020-01-04
5    2020-01-04
6    2020-01-07
7    2020-01-07
8    2020-01-09
9    2020-01-09
10   2020-01-11
11   2020-01-12
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Use [`Series.sub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html)  to subtract `Date` for `s` shifted using [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and use [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) to fill `0` based on mask `m2` and assign this to `Option1`. Similary we obtain `Option2` from `Option1` based on mask `m2`:

```
print(df)
         Date  Fault_Count  Option1  Option2
0  2020-01-01            0      0.0      0.0
1  2020-01-02            0      0.0      0.0
2  2020-01-03            0      0.0      0.0
3  2020-01-04            2      3.0      3.0
4  2020-01-05            2      0.0      0.0
5  2020-01-06            2      0.0      0.0
6  2020-01-07            4      3.0      3.0
7  2020-01-08            4      0.0      0.0
8  2020-01-09            5      2.0      2.0
9  2020-01-10            5      0.0      0.0
10 2020-01-11            0      2.0     -2.0
11 2020-01-12            1      1.0      1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `df['Fault_count_diff'] = ...` and the next line, do:

```
df['cycle'] = (df.Fault_Count.diff() < 0).cumsum()
```

Then to get the dates in between each count change.

Option1. If all calendar dates are present in df:

```
ndays = df.groupby(['cycle', 'Fault_Count']).Date.size()
```

Option2. If there's the possibility of a date not showing up in `df` and you still want to get the calendar days between incidents:

```
ndays = df.groupby(['cycle', 'Fault_Count']).Date.min().diff().dropna()
```